# Texas Parcel Data

Tags: data-request, geospatial, government

Currently, I download any parcel data that I need from the specific county appraisal district for the area that I am working on, or the regional council of governments. The issue is that we spend a ton of time formatting the data we receive from them because it all comes in different formats.

So, I wanted to ask, where do you get your parcel data? I am interested in keeping fields like Ownership, Appraised/Land Values, Land Use, etc. How accurate is this data, and is it affordable?

Comment: Could you tell us where you get the parcel data from and for what counties it covers (if publicly available)? It would add to our knowledge base and it would better help us address your question.

Comment: I do work all over Texas. So say for example I am working in Tarrant County, I could (and do) get parcel data from the Tarrant County Appraisal District (http://www.tad.org/gis-data) or the North Central Texas Council Of Governments (NCTCOG,  http://gis.nctcog.org/clearinghouse_faq.asp).

This works, but the problem is that I do this for dozens of counties and COG's and it all comes in different formats, and therefore we spend many hours manually fixing each one.

The solution that I hope to find is a end-all parcel data source for Texas that has standardized parcel data for download/purchase.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you have seen this coming from Texas Natural Resources Information System that might be what you are looking for.

https://tnris.org/

You can try ESRI's Open Data and it is nice what they do is that you can preview the data and attribute tables before you can download.

ESRI Open Data http://opendata.arcgis.com/

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Formats Issue: We need to get everyone to use a standard open format, in this case I'd say GeoJSON. You work in the trenches, we need you to spread this message in your community. Not necessarily the GeoJSON part (although I prefer it) but the open format part. Aside from all the great, open, machine-readable code being spread about, it'll make your life easier.

Time spent has a lot to do with your tooling, especially if your doing it manually. I highly recommend gdal, it's a game changer. It was a roadblock for me years ago when I was on Win (good luck installing it), and later because I feared the terminal. When I finally used it to batch convert massive files and datasets, it was literally awesome. Like I was in awe @ the power of this library...I still am.

Texas Parcel Data:
OpenAddresses is not a collection of parcels data, [but this is a comprehensive list of texas localities](https://github.com/openaddresses/openaddresses/tree/master/sources/us/tx) that they've got data from. There is also a separate collection for parcels being done, although I can't remember much more than that...it may be worth it for you to contact them.